# Echo string and function?

Tags: php, functions

I'm trying to get "string of text: Edit"

`<?php echo 'string of text: ' . edit_post_link( 'Edit' ); ?>`

but this outputs "Edit string of text:"

How do I make it appear in the correct order? "string of text: Edit"

Answer (score 8):

Use the second parameter of [`edit_post_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/edit_post_link), the `before` parameter:

```
<?php edit_post_link( 'Edit', 'string of text: ' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

edit_post_link() echos the result already. you need to use one of the following examples:

```
<?php echo 'string of text: ' . get_edit_post_link( 'Edit' ); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo 'string of text: '; edit_post_link( 'Edit' ); ?>
```

Comment: In your first example you have pass string parameter to `get_edit_post_link` while it must have first parameter as `post_id` ( interger ).

Comment: @Ravs - First parameter is text for the link, the ID can be optionally passed, but it's the fourth and last parameter. See the documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/edit_post_link).